# Стоит ли выделять данные о количестве и массе сущности "потомок" у сущности "родитель"?

Tags: база-данных

База данных технических средств. Есть таблица с перечнем технических средств. Каждое техническое средство может состоять из определенного количества составных частей, т.е. таких же технических средств.

Примечание:

1. поле "порядок расположения" указывает каким по порядку требуется отображать техническое средство в составе другого технического средства
2. техническое средство которое имеет родителя, тоже может содержать в своем составе другие технические средства и т.д.

Пример:
Системный блок состоит из:

- видеокарта - 2 штуки;
- блок питания - 1 штука;
- материнская плата - 1 штука.

Вопрос: Подскажите пожалуйста, стоит ли выносить атрибуты о количестве (и т.д.) технических средств в составе другого технического средства в отдельную таблицу (например: дополнительные_параметры)? и почему... по вашему мнению?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне, кажется, что лучше без таблицы параметров связей, за кол-во пусть отвечает кол-во строк в таблице "связь между ТС" и порядок перенёс бы в ту же таблицу

Comment: Структура БД зависит от решаемой задачи во всех подробностях. Вы не указали для чего в разрабатываемой системе это самое количество, которое вы собрались хранить, нужно. С точки зрения теории НФ информация о количестве не имеет права хранится в БД, т.к. вычисляется из другой информации, уже находящейся в БД. Но в каких то случаях конечно ее хранение может оказаться оправдано. И кстати тут вообще достаточно только одной таблицы, ссылку на родителя и порядок можно хранить прямо в описании средства

Comment: данные о количестве и составе нужны:

Comment: @Mike данные нужны: а) просмотра структуры в виде иерархического списка (дерева); б) для формирования отчета о составе ТС и их количестве;  г) для сравнительного анализа технического средства с данными о составе технического средства который эксплуатируется (к примеру: по норме: должно быть в составе системного блока №1 - 2 видеокарты. А фактически, в составе изготовленного системного блока №1 с артикулом 456001, имеется 1 видеокарта)

Comment: Ну вот, я не вижу где бы тут использовалось общее количество. видеокарты надо будет считать отдельно. Отчет о составе ТС вряд ли ограничится "тут 5 компонент" без указания каких. так что во всех случаях проще посчитать в самом отчете

Comment: Можно сделать две таблицы. Одна с описаниями тех.средств а во второй состав тех.средства ( idТех.средства, idТех.средства входящего в состав, кол-во, порядок (если он нужен, например, для специфической сортировки) ). @Mike Одной таблицы будет не достаточно, т.к. одно и тоже тех. средство может входить в разные др. тех.средства в разных количествах - если я правильно понял задачу

Comment: @Z.John Да, если техсредство одновременно может входить в состав нескольких, то согласен конечно.

Comment: @Z.John да совершенно верно, одно и тоже средство может входить в разные другие средства. Порядок он нужен, например, для специфической сортировки. Z.John - подскажите пожалуйста, а для самого порядка нужна отдельная таблица, или в этой же таблице можно одним полем типа "число" определять порядок?

Comment: В той же таблице где состав